# Automatically generating API Documentation

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, api, jersey

I am a junior Java developer and I have been working on a big project recently. A part of it was creating RESTful Web services using Jersey for third party clients. Now, after finishing the project, I am tasked to document all the web service calls (I know I should have started that from the beginning) Is there any straightforward tool/Eclipse plugin that generates automatically the API  documentation without a lot of hassle ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used enunciate, it parses the javadoc and JAX-RS annotations of your service classes to generate documentation:

https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki

There is a maven plugin that works well.It also generates client libraries in various languages as well as sample xml for xml based services.

Comment: Codehaus is no more. Check out [enunciate](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki) instead.